# django form.modelchoicefield get selected value

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How to display the "PS1 Failure" instead of value "4" in html template ? with below code

form:

```
class FailureCodeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    failure_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=FailureCodeModel.objects.all().order_by('failure_name'), label='Failure Code')

    class Meta:
        model = FailureCodeModel
        fields = ['failure_name']
```

view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    TarFormField1 = FailureCodeForm(request.POST)

    if TarFormField1.is_valid():

        FailureCode = TarFormField1.cleaned_data['failure_name']
```

template:

```
{{ TarFormField1.failure_name.label_tag }} : {{ failure_name.value }}
```

output:
Failure Code: 4   -----> how to output the selected "PS1 failure" and not the value?

printed html code:

---------
  No Boot
  PS1 Failure
  PrbsTest
  TrafficTest

Comment: show the model.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`get_FOO_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) should do the trick.

```
{{ failure_name.get_value_display }}
```